# "Invalid escape sequence" when trying to use \w, \s, etc. in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

So this regex is so that I can find every type of method declaring of a java file. I believe this should get every instance of the java files I'm using this with but the problem is I keep getting the Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ ).

Here is the string.

```
private String map = "(public|final|protected|private|static|\s) (final|static)* +[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;]) {";
```

This is the part that the Eclipse IDE was erroring on.

```
(public|final|protected|private|static|\s)
```

I understand that there are allot of other similar posts on this but after searching about 10 of them I still couldn't figure out the problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Simplifying the error (e.g. `"\w"`) is always a good way to start ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to double-up the escape character in Java string literals:

```
private String map = "(public|final|protected|private|static|\\s) (final|static)* +[\\w\\<\\>\[\\]]+\\s+(\\w+) *\\([^\\)]*\\) *(\\{?|[^;]) {";
```

Each `\\` in a Java string literal becomes a single `\` in the string itself.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean. I rarely deal with regex so im quite a noob at it.

Comment: @bigfetz - I posted this in the answer. For instance, if you want the regex `\s`, you need to use the Java literal `"\\s"`.

Comment: So I put that into my code and its still giving the same error.

Comment: @bigfetz - You had a lot of `\` characters. Did you fix them all? If so, is it pointing to a different place?

Comment: @bigfetz - Perhaps the problem is the escape sequence `"...\\>..."`. I don't think `\>` is a valid Java regex escape sequence.

Comment: Well I copy and pasted the exact thing you posted into my code and no its giving the error to the entire string.

Comment: Thats it thanks. It works now. The \\> wasn't legal.

Comment: Yeah - and the whammy is the regex literal `"\"` is coded as `"\\\\"`. +1 :)